# How to re import a function - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I make a class to create an axios api service.
inside this class I fetch token(I got it from server and set it on cookie) from cookie.

```
const api = axios.create({
  headers: {
    common: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    post: {

    }
  }
});


const cookies = parseCookies()
const token = cookies.token;
if (token && token !== 'undefined') {
  api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token
}
```

because I import this api service from above component:

```
import api from "../../../services/httpService";
```

after login user, for another api calls cookie is null .

I think I have two solutions:

1. I pass token to each api call like:

   ```
     const config = {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${cookies.token}` }
    };
     api.get('profile',config).then((res) => {
   ```

I don't want use this solution.

2. re-create api import (but I don't know how I can).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When login success, you set token for cookies. And you should update a token for axios instance in this step.

```
// ... set token in cookies
api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token
```

And you don't need this logic when create instance:

```
const cookies = parseCookies()
const token = cookies.token;
if (token && token !== 'undefined') {
  api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token
}
```